# Share memory areas between celery workers on one machine

Tags: python, shared-memory, celeryd

I want to share small pieces of informations between my worker nodes (for example cached authorization tokens, statistics, ...) in celery.

If I create a global inside my tasks-file it's unique per worker (My workers are processes and have a life-time of 1 task/execution).

What is the best practice?
Should I save the state externally (DB), create an old-fashioned shared memory (could be difficult because of the different pool implementations in celery)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about cache like memcached, or key-value stores like Redis?

Comment: That would be a way, but I hoped that I can find a way without an additional dependency.

Comment: It's tiny dependency but it'll solve some problems you may encounter implementing own inter process communication.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally found a decent solution - core python multiprocessing-Manager:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manag = Manager()
serviceLock = manag.Lock()
serviceStatusDict = manag.dict()
```

This dict can be accessed from every process, it's synchronized, but you have to use a lock when accessing it concurrently (like in every other shared memory implementation).

Comment: Hi Gregor, I'd be happy to have your opinion on this issue I'm facing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26088868/asynchronous-task-queue-processing-of-in-memory-data-stucture-in-django

Do you think your solution would be suitable for my problem there?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi cyberjoac, in general this could work, but you need to try out if Django and Celery live in the same process group (which I doubt). Let me know if it works, I'm interested!

Comment: Where do you init this Manager?

Comment: It basically does not matter, @AntonioBeamud - it needs to be in a module which is loaded for every process.

Comment: I have main.py. I have generatereport.py which generates reports and I added the dictionary here. Thanks to you, all the workers have the access to the same dictionary. But I cant access this dictionary in my mian.py. How to achieve this.

Comment: Its not working for me. My celery workers exit with -1