# Asynchronous task queue processing of in-memory data stucture in Django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, singleton, celery

I have a **singleton in-memory data-structure** inside my Django project (some kind of kd-tree that needs to get accessed all across the project).

For those that don't know Django, I believe the same issue would appear with a regular Python code.

I know it's evil (Singleton), and I'm looking for better ways to implement that, but my question here is related to another topic:

I am instantiating the singleton inside my code by calling 
`Singleton.instance()` and it gives me the object correctly, it then stays at some place in the memory inside my `./manage.py runserver`.

The **problem** is that I am making some asynchronous processing with Celery on this same Singleton data-structure (such as reconstructing the kd-tree).

BUT when launching a **Celery worker**, it runs the code within a **different process**, and therefore has a **different memory space**, which means that it works on a totally different instance of the Singleton.

What would be the best Design Pattern to this issue? I have thought of doing all the processing related to my data-structure inside the Django project (without using Celery) but what I liked very much about Celery is that the processing required on the data-structure can take a long-time (around 30 seconds) and it needs to handle concurrency nicely (there could be several requests at the same time to reconstruct the Kd-Tree).

I would be very glad to have some insights for this since I'm not making any progress those last 3 days.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your question sounds like a classic inter-process communication issue rather than having a singleton involved.

The right answer will depend very much on how you get the state in your celery task. By default you could try pass by parameter or use a cache or storage mechanism to share the state between the two processes.

Perhaps if you could provide more information about the states you want to share and how you need it, it would be possible to give better suggestions.

Comment: The data structure is very big (could reach 2 GB), so that I would rather not have to deal with an extra layer of Redis, memcached or else...
Isn't there a way to share an "object" in Python to Celery?

Comment: But you specifically wanted processing to be done in a separate process, which is the point of Celery; and processes don't share memory. This is not a Python restriction, but a general point about processes.

Comment: Also note you'll have exactly the same cross-process communication issues when you move from the devserver to a proper production server, which will almost certainly use multiple processes - each will have their own copy of the singleton.

Comment: Now I get the limitations of doing it on a different process.
What would be my best bet to solve this issue?
What would be the best way to share the state? Should I look into IPC (like multithreading library of python) or more into things like Redis, Memcached etc?

The problem I see with those options is that I will need to serialize / unserialize the data structure inside the memory on every request.

Also Daniel what would be the way to go to deal with those IPC issues on a production server?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you solve the problem?? I'm also in same situation