# How to have the access of the shared memory of different workers

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, celery

[Share memory areas between celery workers on one machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565542/share-memory-areas-between-celery-workers-on-one-machine)

In this post the author demonstrates how to share the dictionary among the workers. Thanks to him I have achieved this. But now I want to read that shared memory from my main.py.

I have main.py. I have generatereport.py which generates reports and I added the shared dictionary here. All the workers now have the access to the same dictionary. Now how can I access this shared dictionary from main.

main.py

```
from report import reportgen
from flask import Flask, request, send_from_directory, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@ns.route('/GenerateReport')
@ns.doc('Generate PDF')
class GeneratePdf(Resource):
    def get(self):
        task = generate.delay(myDict, uuid)
        return {"request":"made"}

@ns.route('/pdfstatus')
@ns.doc('status')
class statusPdf(Resource):
    def get(self):
        print(report.serviceStatusDict)
```

cel.py

```
from celery import Celery
from report import reportgen

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def generate(myDict, name):
    data = generateJson(myDict)
    pdfgen.serviceStatusDict[name] = "Rest Performed"
    reportgen(data, name)
```

report.py

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
manag = Manager()
serviceLock = manag.Lock()
serviceStatusDict = manag.dict()
def reportgen():
   serviceStatusDict["uuid"] = "Generated the report"
   //....//
```

Comment: Post your code.  Where are you defining the `Manager`?

Comment: I am defining the Manager in generatereport.py

Comment: The author said the manager needs to be in a module which is loaded for every process. I felt that module is generatereport.py as it loaded for everyworker. Thanks @PatrickHaugh

Comment: I am adding code to the question.